# Macbook Pro Battery 0% and wrong date

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging, power

**Model: MacBook Pro Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015**

While I was working, I didn't realize that the battery was low and as a result, my MacBook Pro shut down when the battery had no power. So, then I plugged in the charger and powered it on. This time I noticed something was strange. The battery was stuck in 0% for like around 10 minutes and the date got reset to 1st January 2017. I tried resetting NVRAM. Nothing happened. So, then I ran diagnostics and I got this as a result:

[image]

#### Here's the battery information:

[image]

#### Here's a screenshot from Battery Health:

[image]

Now it is pretty obvious that you might ask me to change the battery because the screenshots say so, but I want a final opinion from you guys what to do next. Everything was working fine and all of a sudden this happens. I feel if I plugged the charger in time, I wouldn't have to see all this. And also a new battery isn't exactly affordable for me at the moment. And it is also important to note that while the charger is on, it shows orange LED. So, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your battery is dead.

You need to replace the battery.   Granted, it's a bit young at just under two years and 820 cycles, but it's not uncommon nor unheard of.  Unfortunately, batteries die for any number of factors.

With your specific battery, it appears that it won't take a charge, thus it cannot hold one.

> Everything was working fine and all of a sudden this happens. I feel
> if I plugged the charger in time, I wouldn't have to see all this.

There are a [number of factors that contribute to premature battery death](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238125/119271) - it could have been defective from the factory or you could have subjected it to extreme conditions.  Perhaps something in between.  The point is, it happens.  There is *nothing* you could have done to [prevent your battery from degrading](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/194703/119271).

> ...also a new battery isn't exactly affordable for me at the moment.
> And it is also important to note that while the charger is on, it
> shows orange LED. So, what should I do?

First off, the orange LED means it's sending voltage to the charging circuit or "charging" for short.   It doesn't mean it's "successfully charging" the battery.

Getting an Apple Store to [change out your battery will be very expensive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231914/119271) (minimum $500).  However, a [replacement battery](http://radnex.us/macbook-pro-2013-2015-battery) alone is fairly inexpensive (around $70 USD) if you are willing to change it out yourself.  ifixit.com has an excellent [step-by-step guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+Battery+Replacement/45137) to walk you through it.  They rank it as difficult, not because it's complex (it actually quite simple) but because the battery is glued in and you have to be careful.

Comment: So, after I woke up from sleep, I saw the date and time got reset once again to 1st Jan 2017 after powering up my MacBook Pro. I guess I have no other option than changing the battery.

Comment: A lot of these batteries are made in China, is this something you could source from there instead?  Just curious....

Comment: Well, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I saw your battery is already very close to dead with 4000mAh max capacity (the 100% healthy battery has 6500mAh). So everything could happen. You need to replace it. 
I'm not sure how it died so fast... Actually I bought the same model on 2016 spring and keep using it everyday until today (heavy use) and it still has 5700mAh.

Comment: I bought MacBook Pro just for heavy use and also as a primary laptop. And could you define heavy use? For me heavy use would be gaming a lot(around 7-8 hours a week) and leaving it on overnight. Its kinda funny because my previous laptop's(non Apple laptop) battery lasted for full 3 and a half years under very heavy use after which I had to replace it. But in the post, I forgot to mention that my MBP fell face first from a table once. It was around 85 cm fall. Could that shock be a reason for the reduced battery life?

Comment: I don't think that shock will do have harm to battery. And actually that really sounds weird because I have been using it as my primary laptop using it everyday work and entertainment for more than 10 hours per day and never care about the battery life, even never shut it down.....But whatever, you can take your laptop to Apple and replace a new battery. It's not very expensive (around 100dollars I remember). Then everything will be fine.

Comment: Well, I live in India and an authorised Apple service centre told me it is a little above 100 USD.