# Mac runs as long as plugged in, but unpredictably shuts off otherwise - clock resets

Tags: battery, power

I have a MacBook Pro, as shown in the image below.  Also, as I think it might use a lot of power, I run Ubuntu on a vagrant machine to test website apps.

Recently (last 2-3 months), the battery would go down to about 10%, and the Mac would just shut down. Go black.  Total restart.  **AND**, the clock was reset to 6:00AM.  I would reset the clock and go on with life.

Then, I started noticing this would happen at say 23% power, or 45%.  Now, it's unpredictable when it will happen.  It's never happened when I'm plugged in.

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the standard SMC and NVRAM resets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macbook Pro Battery 0% and wrong date](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326368/macbook-pro-battery-0-and-wrong-date)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it needs a new battery.

Get [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) (freeware) & test.

Comment: I can't see why this got a down vote....