# Battery Status Bar broken -> Says 100%, mac does not fully charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

**Charging Behavior**

From 1% battery on, this Mac claims to need six hours to fully charge. At some point the status bar breaks and shows 100% within 20 minutes of charging. As far as I am aware, Mac optimizes charging and stops when it is fully charged. It is impossible to completely charge within twenty minutes.

[image: exponential battery percentage graph]

**Behavior on No-Power-Supply**

So when I leave the computer without charge for several minutes, it dies. During these minutes the battery percentage won't shrink. The physical battery has a cycles count of ca. ten +/- so it's definitely not a battery problem.

**Product Information**

```
- MacBook Pro Intel based
- Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400)
- 13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports

From System Information:
Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  11
  Condition:    Normal
```

I'm asking for advice/ help if it is possible to fix the battery without hardware reparations as this seems to be a software bug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The post I made asks for help on how to fix the battery problems. Mac dies 1 minute without charge. Weird behaviour (detailed description in the post) when charging. Please clarify which specific part of the problem you could not resolve.

Comment: Please edit your question/add to comments what vintage the MBP you are having problems with, and the version of macOS installed.

Comment: How old is the MBP? Have you tried resetting the SMC? Have you tried downloading an app like Coconut Battery, which can provide detailed information about the health of your battery? Failing batteries can report misleading or incorrect data, so it's probably that. I'd take it to an Apple Store to have them check it.

Comment: @IconDaemoni've added the mac os version

Comment: How old is the MBP, though?

Comment: @IconDaemon 13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports

Comment: Please add the hardware specs to the question as requested. Comments can be deleted.

Comment: Progress! Per guarantee I got a new Mac replacement, since the battery was, indeed, broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your battery needs to be replaced.

> So when I leave the computer without charge for several minutes, it dies. During these minutes the battery percentage won't shrink. The physical battery has a cycles count of ca. ten +/- so it's definitely not a battery problem.

If it dies while on battery power only after a few minutes, the battery is at fault.  The fact that the charge indicator doesn’t change means nothing; the battery has a dead cell or cells and is not holding a charge.

#### Battery status is a *calculation*

> From 1% battery on, this Mac claims to need six hours to fully charge. At some point the status bar breaks and shows 100% within 20 minutes of charging. As far as I am aware, Mac optimizes charging and stops when it is fully charged. It is impossible to completely charge within twenty minutes.

There is no “electronic dip stick” that gives you a real time view of your battery’s charge level.  it’s voltage and current draw are measured and compared to its known design specs and a percent and time value calculated.

In other words, 100% doesn’t mean it’s fully chraged. It means what it is reading now “looks like” it’s fully charged.

#### TL;DR

Your battery has failed and must be replaced. There is no software tweak that is going to fix this. Unfortunately, all batteries will fail.  It’s only a matter of when.

See the following links for additional reading:

- [Mac Battery malfunctioning in just 2 years](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393631/119271)
- [Battery not charging at only 35 cycles - recoverable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389845/119271)
- [My Macbook Pro M1 2020 is not starting up without being plugged in and battery icon shows a cross with fans turned on](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/452993/119271)