# My MacBook isn't charged since 2016, can I still charge now?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charger

I have a MacBook that requires a MagSafe charger, but my charger broke in mid 2016. My MacBook was holding 40%+ charge and no longer being charged. I am wondering if I can still charge it today? If yes, I am going to order a charger online.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Is your MacBook currently powering on? If not, are you able to see any symbol on screen when powering on?

Comment: Which model MacBook?  The battery of my MBP8,2 (early 2011) is dead, after the last half a year on the shelf.

Comment: It’s model is A1181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no other way to find out than to try it.

In general there's nothing that says that a battery must stop working because it hasn't been charged in two years - batteries like those really age more due to heavy use rather than lying around on a shelf. So unless something bad happened to the computer or the battery over those two years, it is probably going to work just fine.

Comment: Exactly. +1.  Plugging it in and seeing if it works is the exact same thing a tech will do (except the tech will bill you an hourly rate for doing so.)  Even if it is the battery, [it can be replaced](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231914/119271), but I doubt you'll have to for exactly the reason @jksoegaard says.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/194703/119271) for more details.